# Better to customize UINavigationBar with image or programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I know that there are two distinct ways to customize a UINavigationBar: you can either set the background image to some custom png, or you could customize the bar's appearance in code, programmatically. If my aim is to support iOS 4,5,6 does it make sense to try to customize the bar's appearance through code?

I essentially want a navigationbar **without any gradience**, **a solid color**, **rounded corners**, and **an extremely thin shadow line**. I would post an image below but I need at least 10 reputation points :(

I've started with the following code to address the no gradience and solid color issues, and I've placed this in the .m file of my rootviewcontroller before the @implementation of the class itself, but to no avail:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
@end
```

I also have implemented this code to round out the corners, which **works**:

```
CALayer *capa = [self.navigationController navigationBar].layer;
[capa setShadowColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[capa setShadowOpacity:0.85f];
[capa setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.5f)];
[capa setShadowRadius:2.0f];
[capa setShouldRasterize:YES];


//Round
CGRect bounds = capa.bounds;
bounds.size.height += 10.0f;    //I'm reserving enough room for the shadow
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

[capa addSublayer:maskLayer];
capa.mask = maskLayer;
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target iOS < 5 then the `UIAppearance` won't help you because it is supported only for iOS >= 5.

So in my opinion, using a `png` file for the navigation bar's background is faster and maybe safer. Depending on your desired result you can do it from code and also make it faster, just create a `BaseViewController` that will handle the navigation bar's appearance (background, title, buttons etc) and all your custom view controllers can inherit from this `BaseViewController`, but this implementation in some cases can has it's own drawbacks since you can't inherit from multiple classes in iOS, and I'm afraid that you will find out this a little bit late when you will get to a point when you will want to have features from a view controller that doesn't inherit from the `BaseViewController`.

On the other hand, creating the color and the graphics from code will probably raise issues from the beloved designers who will want 1px left/up/right/down/diagonal/etc, and in this way you will have headaches (happen to me).

If you are targeting iOS >=5 then `UIAppearance` is your friend.

So in conclusion, if you are targeting iOS >= 5 use `UIAppearance` if not, if you have a more complex (gradient, lines, strange colors) UI for your nav bar use `png`, if you have simple (one flat color) UI for nav bar, you can do it from code with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance proxy of the UINavigationBar is there to set the default for ALL UINavigationBars if you want ALL of the bars to change then do it programmatically, if you want only 1 to change then do it in the storyboard both methods should have the same outcome for the appearance of your NavigationBar

The color/shadow should be with in the image, but be mindful of the fact that you shouldn't change the height of the navigation bar...

if you are able to have the image have the rounded corners and the shadow baked in

if you are not you will have to do it in code by using your code above

That is a simple method... a more advanced method would be creating a UINavigationBar item in your storyboard with an associated IBOutlet, setting an outlet to that item, set all the properties from with in the storyboard like the background image, then with in the viewDidLoad method set the IBOutlet of the UINavigationBar to the UINavigationBar of the UINavigationController of the UIViewController that you are loading. Also, you can round the corners of the UINavigationBar here if you desire.